# Python code to read excel document and verify if info on scanned paperwork is among the list then separate items in different files

Tags: python, excel, classification, directory-structure, pdftotext

I find myself in a situation where multiple sheets of paper are printed out, containing information that must be verified on an excel document i receive through e-mail. My role is to check if the received sheets are among the excel list by checking their assigned ID, name, phone number and other information. I have to separate them in piles for 3 different regions *(each region has a different format)* then classify them by priority. I have to separate the ones that are not listed on my excel file and put them aside to later be checked against another excel list on the next day, or the next, or the next and so on. Even if they aren't listed i must categorize them. I also sometimes get cancellations.

I have the possibility to scan the printed sheets and send them back to my computer in PDF via e-mail, which led me to think that there was most certainly a way for the process of verification to be sped up thanks to the power of coding! (a power which I've only discovered about two months ago through python).

{sidenote} I've tried to make the following a bit more readable by using **bold** and *italic* fonts to express these two things:

*I would like to find a way to automate these tasks*

**This information may be relevant to the code**

Please guide me in this adventure to learn code and do not hesitate to recommend rewriting or adding to these lines if you feel my questions/explanations are lacking or hard to understand, i would be glad to accommodate. I beg of you to educate me and point out my mistakes. I will now try my best to explain what I expect the code to do and provide what information is relevant to the case.

- **1**-*Looking on the sheet of paper to find information relevant to classification.* I have to look through sheets of paper for certain keywords or numbers that let me know how to classify this particular sheet. I've tried to find a program to scan images/PDF to text, but 'pytesseract' was the only option i almost understood. I'm curious to know what works best in my situation. It would be nice to have the possibility to set the **number of keywords** i'm looking for, they're **length** and if they have **alphanumerical values**. Their usual positioning on paper would also be a nice option(I expect this to be asking for too much and am sorry if it is). *So the first step would be to analyse the scanned sheets for the desired information and the second step would be to create folders in which to place all sheets based on the information we can get from the analysis all in accordance with the classification system* (see 2 & 3 below).
- **2**-*Separating each scanned sheet into different folders according to the classification system.* I'm thinking that the best way to classify each scanned sheet of paper is to create folders in which to redirect them for easy manipulation if one of them is misplaced, I may be wrong. I'm guessing the order of classification should be based on **priority** so as such: **[1-region, 2-date, 3-ready, 4-employee, 5-no list, 6-canceled]** => 3 main folders for the **[3 different regions]** holding folders for different **[date]**, each date has 2 sub-folders: **[ready / not ready]**, holding within both of them the sub-folders: **[employee / not employee]**. Also 1 folder for the **[canceled]** type is needed and 1 for the ones that won't fit into the predetermined categories **[not listed](see 4 below)**.
- - **2.1**-*I sometimes get notified of **canceled** forms and need to place them aside.* A cancelled form will have a "canceled' written on it and will not have the information necessary to determine [ready / not ready] or [employee / not employee]. These pages **still need to be divided among the 3 different regions and date(if possible)**, but do not need to be classified further (sometimes the desired date is missing from its designated place on the sheet, while another date is present in another spot on the sheet, so I think only regions should be taken into account).
- **3**-*Recognizing what data or values are expected/desired.* Each sheet of paper has unique information/keywords that will allow it to be classified by [region] and [date], as [ready / not ready] and [employee / not employee]. To determine if one is ready depends on which of the following is written on the page: [r/nr] = [**DT / NON-DT**] (either of these values should always be present on paper if not then it's most probably a canceled form). [e/ne] =[**G8, G9, G18, G23 / anything other than this selection is not-employee**]
- **4**-*Pass through every scanned page to see if its information is listed on one of the rows in the excel file and then classify each sheet into its respective category,* => this is to certify that my scanned papers are already listed on my excel sheet or not **[listed / not listed]**. The excel files I use to classify my sheets have many unnecessary columns, the only ones i need are: **presence, ID, last name, first name, comment and phone number.** In my excel files every row is a different item and columns hold the sets of information such as ID and Names. Also each scanned piece of paper may come from one of **three regions, each with its own sheet layout.** I need to be able to to classify my [not listed] selection and run them through the system against another list later on.

So I believe this is all the necessary information behind the main idea of the tasks i wish to automate through a Python code. To read scanned sheets and an excel document in the hopes of verifying if the individual scanned sheets are the ones cited among a designated list by checking for a set number of factors while finally creating multiple folders for the sheets to be placed in order of importance in.

Hope this is something a beginner can learn!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely learn everything required to automate these tasks albeit it will take some time and effort. Just follow the steps with dedication and you will reach there in a few weeks/ months (depending on your pace):

1. You will want to start by learning the basics of programming (using python as your main language).
2. Moving on, you will want to explore libraries such as `openpyxl` to interact with excel files with ease.
3. Then, you will want to explore libraries that can read and categorize data from PDFs (you do not need to understand the intricacies of PDFs as long as you can find the right libraries to do the work for you with some googling).

Since your goal is just automation (and not learning Computer Science fundamentals like data structures), I would suggest going through **"Automate the boring stuff with Python"** [https://automatetheboringstuff.com/]. It is an AMAZING resource for total beginners (and even people with prior knowledge who want to understand practical applications of Python in automation).